# Typing an SSH command doesnt go to a new line

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

While typing a nice long command though SSH (ie. `rsync copy`), the line doesn't shift to a new line and just overlaps the current line when i hit the right edge of the screen. Any suggestion on why this is happening and how to fix?

The setup is below (and an example command).

Debian6 64bit - Its a DOMU VM (XEN)

`/test/test-srv release]$ rsync -avzh --dry-run /test/long/source/path/blah/blah/blah/ /test/long/target/path/etc/etc/etc/etc/etc/etc/test`

The bit in bold is the overlapping part which should just push the cmd prompt up a line.

Image Example:

[image]

Comment: have you tried to resize your terminal via `Edit->Profile Preferences, General` page..?

Comment: I've seen this sort of thing happen when your TERM environment variable doesn't match the terminal type of your terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of your colored prompt. You neglected to mark ANSI escape codes as invisible.

Bash doesn't know what your terminal does, so it relies on you to tell it which parts of the prompt are non-printing and which are not. You do this by adding `\[ \]` around them.

```
# Example bad prompt which wraps lines incorrectly like you describe
PS1='\033[01;34m\w \$ \033[00m'
```

Here, `\033[01;34m` and `\033[00m` don't show up on the terminal (that is, they don't move the cursor), they just change the color of the following text. To show this, we wrap them in `\[ \]`:

```
# Prompt from above that wraps correctly
PS1='\[\033[01;34m\]\w \$ \[\033[00m\]'
```